# Visual Studio 2010 loses JS formatting rules

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, formatting

As the title says, Visual Studio just forgive my formatting options selection.

In `Tools > Options > Text editor > JScript > Formatting` I just disabled all the four Automatic formatting. Sometimes it seems to lose my selections, and I've to change it again.

Anyone knows why?

My version is VS2010 SP1 English running on Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: Where are your settings being saved? Are they being overwritten by version control or something else?

Comment: It's not my case, the settings are in C:\Users\[my user]\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Settings and the files are not under any type of source versioning

Comment: Are you on a corporate PC that may be overwriting those files?

Comment: I'm on a corporate PC, but I'm the only user of this machine. I'm sure

Comment: Some companies run scripts that keep common directories clean or remove file changes.  I'm not saying that's happening for you (in fact I certainly hope no companies are modifying developer settings files) but it's just something to consider.

Comment: Just as something to try, move your settings files to a different folder and see if you still lose changes.

Comment: It's possibly a bug. I've had it happen to myself numerous times, and colleagues have experienced the same.